# YAML syntax for set_fact and vars in ansible

Tags: syntax, ansible, yaml

I have difficulties to get the differences between the following syntaxes when I set vars or facts in a YAML role:

```yaml
vars:
  app_path1: "{{ (ansible_facts.env.ProgramFiles + '\\\\' + item.installation_directory) if item.executable else root_dir }}"
  app_path2: >
      {{ (ansible_facts.env.ProgramFiles + '\\' + item.installation_directory) if item.executable else root_dir }}   
  app_path3: |
      {{ (ansible_facts.env.ProgramFiles + '\\' + item.installation_directory) if item.executable else root_dir }}
```

Here is the result:

```json
{        
  "app_path1": "C:\\Program Files\\\\MyCompany\\TheAppName",
  "app_path2": "C:\\Program Files\\\\MyCompany\\TheAppName\n",
  "app_path3": "C:\\Program Files\\\\MyCompany\\TheAppName\n"
}
```

Why `app_path2` and `app_path3` added a mysterious `\n` at the end? And why must I escape twice the backslashes in app_path1? It's a kind of black magic for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the new line, this is the behaviour of those two YAML style indicator.
There is [*"strip chomping indicator"*](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#8112-block-chomping-indicator) to get rid of them though:

So, `app_path2` and `app_path3` should be

```yaml
app_path2: >-
  {{ 
    (ansible_facts.env.ProgramFiles + '\\' + item.installation_directory) 
    if item.executable else root_dir 
  }}
app_path3: |-
  {{ 
    (ansible_facts.env.ProgramFiles + '\\' + item.installation_directory) 
    if item.executable else root_dir 
  }}
```

As for the double escaping, this is quite simple, since you are in a double quoted string, this remark applies:

> The double-quoted style is specified by surrounding “`"`” indicators. This is the only style capable of expressing arbitrary strings, by using “`\`” escape sequences. This comes at the cost of having to escape the “`\`” and “`"`” characters.

<sup>*Source: https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/#73-flow-scalar-styles*</sup>

Since you want to display two backslashes and that you have to escape them both, you end up with four of them.

---

*Note*: a pretty good tool for the explanation of all this is https://yaml-multiline.info